# How could I desorb the CO2 molecules contained in the pores of activated carbon?

Tags: green-chemistry, carbon-family, van-der-waals-behavior

I have CO2 trapped in my activated carbon. What would be the most environmentally sustainable way to release it? I have heard of PSA (Pressure Swing Adsorption), which works when the adsorbent is subjected to a high-pressure environment, allowing it to adsorb CO2. Then, the pressure is reduced, causing the CO2 to desorb from the adsorbent and collect as a concentrated stream. But can that even work on activated carbon? Or is my best bet a temperature swing system (TSS), which requires lots of heat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and simplest way to desorb adsorbed $\ce{CO2}$ molecules is to heat the charcoal to the highest temperature where it does not burn.

Comment: In most environments, heating the carbon is most efficient -- low density and moderate electrical resistivity makes it easy and efficient to heat the carbon directly. However, outside Earth's atmosphere, one could just leave it *in vacuo*, warmed by sunlight, and wait for it to outgas.